# Crashing when trying to set visibility to layout

Tags: java, android

My program is crashing when I try to change visibility of layout. What am I doing wrong?

My code and logcat is here :

**MainActivity.java:**

```
private LinearLayout infolayer; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    findViewById(R.id.info);
    infolayer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.inflayer); //listview id from xml
    findViewById(R.id.master);

public void openInfo(View view){

    if(infolayer.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) infolayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else infolayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**activity_main xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#40ff6f"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/inflayer"></LinearLayout>
```

Crash logcat:

```
 11-25 11:39:09.669      251-616/? E/HtcAudPMB﹕ getOutput() IOProfile is null.
 11-25 11:39:09.669     251-1365/? E/HtcAudPMB﹕ getOutput() IOProfile is null.
 11-25 11:39:09.669      251-617/? E/HtcAudPMB﹕ getOutput() IOProfile is null.
 11-25 11:39:09.679      251-611/? E/ACDB-LOADER﹕ Error: ACDB AFE returned = -8
 11-25 11:39:09.679  30032-30032/com.example.training E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3673)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4280)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17984)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3668)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4280)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17984)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.training.MainActivity.openInfo(MainActivity.java:84)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3668)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4280)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17984)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

  11-25 11:39:09.689      595-677/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Process: com.example.training
  11-25 11:39:09.689      595-677/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Package: com.example.training v1 (1.0)
  11-25 11:39:09.699      595-677/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ Application Label: training
  11-25 11:39:09.709      251-611/? E/AudioStreamOutALSA﹕ PCM_Write set_amp_mode,1
  11-25 11:39:10.460     851-3237/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.htc.idlescreen.setting.provider
  11-25 11:40:14.939  30871-30871/? E/BlurCheckin﹕ exception in static initializer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.motorola.android.provider.CheckinEvent
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at com.motorola.camera.BlurCheckin.<clinit>(BlurCheckin.java:202)
        at com.motorola.camera.CameraApp.onCreate(CameraApp.java:103)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5085)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:162)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1476)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/motorola/android/provider/CheckinEvent
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at com.motorola.camera.BlurCheckin.<clinit>(BlurCheckin.java:202)
        at com.motorola.camera.CameraApp.onCreate(CameraApp.java:103)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5085)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:162)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1476)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.motorola.android.provider.CheckinEvent" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.motorola.camera-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.motorola.camera-1, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at com.motorola.camera.BlurCheckin.<clinit>(BlurCheckin.java:202)
        at com.motorola.camera.CameraApp.onCreate(CameraApp.java:103)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5085)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:162)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1476)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   11-25 11:40:14.939  30871-30871/? E/BlurCheckin﹕ Checkin class does not exist:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.motorola.checkinwrapper.CheckinEventWrapper
   11-25 11:41:20.048     251-1365/? E/HtcAudPMB﹕ getOutput() IOProfile is null.
   11-25 11:41:20.048      251-616/? E/HtcAudPMB﹕ getOutput() IOProfile is null.
   11-25 11:41:20.048      251-617/? E/HtcAudPMB﹕ getOutput() IOProfile is null.
   11-25 11:41:20.058      251-611/? E/ACDB-LOADER﹕ Error: ACDB AFE returned = -8
   11-25 11:41:20.088      251-611/? E/AudioStreamOutALSA﹕ PCM_Write set_amp_mode,1
```

Comment: You forgot to call `setContentView()` before you are manipulating with layout. You need to do this, otherwise instances of elements in layout are not created and initialised - reason of `NPE`.

Answer (score 0):

As Geralt has already correctly commented, try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(infolayer) // Usually the Layout comes from the generated 
                              // R.java so something like R.layout.infolayer

    // your code...

}
```